# Deleting a question while I write an answer

Tags: discussion

Admittedly, the question was a tad inane. :-) Maybe, the n00b simply didn't formulate it sensibly, as it could be interpreted to mean something legit. Still, I bothered to take some time to write a sensible answer. One second before I hitted "submit", it was deleted. Words like percent sign, dollar and ampersand could only be heard in my room, thank God.

I don't think this is the luckiest handling of things (e.g. a post could be temporarily locked, but I immediately see other problems with that; I also have no idea how the answerer could be warned - note that the question had no downvotes yet).
Either
a) What is your opinion on the matter? (yes, this should not happen/no, this is your natural risk as answerer/no, alternatives would only create larger problems),
or preferrably
b) Where was this already discussed at length on meta? ("Similar Questions" possibly would take ages. At least a quick google gave nothing.)