# When is it OK for somebody to delete a question they have asked?

Tags: discussion

With reference to [this question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/975/deleting-a-question-while-i-write-an-answer) when the OP answered a question, hit submit only to be told that the question had been deleted by the questioner while he was writing his answer.

Clearly there are situations where a question has gained enough answers, votes or maybe even been there for long enough that the OP cannot delete it. What are these criteria? Can they modified for Chess? (I'm guessing the answer is "No"). Should they be modified to make them stricter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it works now is explained [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/643262):

> You can't delete your own question if it:
>
> - has an answer with upvotes (even if that answer has a net zero or negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - has an answer with an awarded bounty
> - has at least one other question that is marked as a duplicate of your question

It seems unlikely that these criteria will be changed only for Chess, but the moderators and users with [access to the moderator tools](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) could decide to (vote to) undelete any question that has been deleted and they think is worth preserving. Recently deleted questions are accessible in the [moderator tools](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tools). Keeping track of this is quite inconvenient though,but at least reacting to individual requests on Meta is possible.